# Set tailwind styles in react js application

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have this styles in my react js application. I use tailwind css to add styles:

```
const size = '300px'
const getStyle = (s) => `[@media_screen_and_(min-width:${s})]:bg-[red]`
<p className={getStyle(size)}>hi</p>
```

and i expect after 300px to set backgraund:red for the `p` tag.

 Doing this i don't get any result. 
 NOTE: i need this way of setting the breakpoints.

Question: Why i don't get the result and how to fix?

Comment: It will not be working due to it being a dynamic class name. tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names

Comment: How many different `size` values will you have? You probably need to include them all in your code or safelist them

Comment: The size will be as a component prop, so for all tags the size will be the same. So if I will have many sizes then it will not work but if I will have only one it should work?

Comment: @Asking if you add in your safelist section of config or any file included in content section for example `[@media_screen_and_(min-width:300px)]:bg-[red]` - 300px will work,  `[@media_screen_and_(min-width:500px)]:bg-[red]` - 500px will work and so on. When you're using dynamic class names make sure it has been included somewhere in your app without concatenation but as it is with correct values. However you may pass into safleist function which will loop over every possible size

Comment: @stickyuser, the `size` number depends by the user. So user can add whatever he wants. I think the idea with adding the sizes in safelist will be too problematic, because the user in theory can add the numbers in this range 300 - 1000. Do you know a solution for this?

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka, could you please help me taking into account my last comment for `stickyuser`?

Comment: @Asking for a big range like that I would recommend you look for other ways to add the media queries outside of Tailwind. Tailwind is not a good solution in this case. There are other react libraries that can help you do media queries.

Answer (score 1):

As I'm not working with React, I'll give an answer with VueJS but I'll simulate same situation

Let's say we have this class

```html
<div class="p-10 [@media_screen_and_(min-width:500px)]:bg-[red]"></div>
```

Everything will work as expected - you see red figure when screen size is bigger than 500px

Now we have this situation

```html
<div class="p-10 [@media_screen_and_(min-width:500px)]:bg-[red]"></div>

<div v-for="size in ['300', '500', '700']" :key="size" :class="`p-10 [@media_screen_and_(min-width:${size}px)]:bg-[red]`">
    {{ size }}
</div>"
```

You would expect four (1 static and 3 within loop) red figures but you'll see only two. Why?

That is because Tailwind is not smart enough to understand you're within loop and passing dynamic size - it is reads whole document as a **STRING**. It is not loads classes from compiled files, but resources - and there are no `[@media_screen_and_(min-width:300px)]:bg-[red]` class - only `[@media_screen_and_(min-width:${size}px)]:bg-[red]` (it is really reads it with dollar sign `$`) - and in DOM we have no such class (it is being generated as `[@media_screen_and_(min-width:300px)]:bg-[red]`, etc). But why does second figure within loop is red? Because we have static class behind with value of 500px. Tailwind finds it, compiles CSS for `[@media_screen_and_(min-width:500px)]:bg-[red]` and now second loop element may be styled with red background. If you remove static element and leave loop only - you'll see no red figures at all. Such behavior explained [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names). So you need either pass compiled class name as it is or [safelist](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes) classes

Within your Tailwind config add these lines

```
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
    // ...
    safelist: [
        '[@media_screen_and_(min-width:300px)]:bg-[red]',
        '[@media_screen_and_(min-width:500px)]:bg-[red]',
        '[@media_screen_and_(min-width:700px)]:bg-[red]',
    ]
}
```

and now you'll see the result. But this looks messy and if you need more and more sizes you'll need to add a new line. Remember - `tailwind.config.js` is Javascript file and it can handle any Javascript within. So we can do something like

```
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
    // ...
    safelist: ['300', '500', '700'].map(size => `[@media_screen_and_(min-width:${size}px)]:bg-[red]`)
}
```

This will generate same result. If you need to create it from range, like from 300 to 700, it may look like

```
// tailwind.config.js

const safelist = Array.from(Array(401).keys())
            .map(size => size + 300)
            .map(size => `[@media_screen_and_(min-width:${size}px)]:bg-[red]`)

module.exports = {
    // ...
    safelist,
}
```

*Again - any Javascript logic, this is just my examples, you may have different approach in creating such array, but remember - safelist should be an array of classes or objects with patterns*

Now every size from `300px` to `700px` will be safelisted. However it will create 400 properties (!) of such CSS for every size in compiled file

```css
@media screen and (min-width:300px) {
    .\[\@media_screen_and_\(min-width\:300px\)\]\:bg-\[red\] {
        --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
        background-color: rgb(255 0 0 / var(--tw-bg-opacity))
    }
}

// 301, 302, 303 and so on till 700...
```

and for every user, I guess, you will need only one of these. So I would not recommend safelist range but it may depends on your task. If you have to use such range and only one will be used, I would suggest to change strategy for this and do not use Tailwind variants but generate style tag within `head` section - this way it will be only one style instead of 400. Tailwind is great, but it's not perfect - it is just a tool and if it creates more problems than it solves - consider another local solution.

I hope it helps you to understand logic behind dynamic classes in Tailwind

Answer (score 0):

Steps to integrate tailwind on react JS project

Step1: npx create-react-app my-project

```
Step2: cd my-project

Step3: npm i tailwindcss postcss-cli autoprefixer@9.8.6

Step4: npx tailwindcss init --full

Step5: add this to content on tailwind css:
content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
],

Step 6: create postcss.config.js:

Step 7: Add this line to postcss file

const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');
module.exports = {
  plugins: [tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js'), require('autoprefixer')],
}


Step 8: add below line in package json

"scripts": {
    "build:css":"postcss src/style/tailwind.css -o src/style/main.css",
    "build:watch":"postcss src/style/tailwind.css -o src/style/main.css --watch"
}

Step 9: create a style folder with src folder and add 2 new files
 1. tailwind.css
    add these lines in tailwind file

    @tailwind base;
    @tailwind components;
    @tailwind utilities;

 2. main.css


 Step 10: remove index.css from index.js file and import './style/main.css';

 Step 11: <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold border-2 text-gray w-30">
      Hello world!
    </h1>

 Step 12: npm run build:css

 Step 13: npm start
```